# How to force an SSRS parameter to be grayed out using an expression?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-expression

Looking everywhere on Google and cannot find the answer.

Is there an SSRS expression to grey out a parameter. So by default it is visible and can be selected. I want to to be grayed out and not selectable until a prior parameter is selected. I'd like to do this with an expression instead of cascading parameters. This is a special case. There must be something I can do in an if statement to make the parameter grayed out if the other parameter does not have a value selected. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to give always a value to the parameters from the form in the preview or by using parameters in cascading but maybe a default value from behind. It would depends on your code and what do you need to return for the dataset. I suppose that the dataset has fixed columns. Do you use sql inline or a store procedure? can you give an example of your code?